# How to extract dataframes from a list of dataframes (in individual variables)

Tags: list, dataframe, variables, global-variables, glob

i want to get the dataframes from below code in individual dataframes (declared as variables),
so that i can paste them to specific locations using xlsx writet package.

below is the code

import os
import glob
import pandas as pd
paths = os.listdir(r"\USER-PC\Users\user\Desktop\combined")
csvfiles = []
for path in paths:
if path.endswith(".csv"):
csvfiles.append(path)
csvfiles
files_list = [pd.read_csv(f) for f in csvfiles]

i want to extract the dataframes individually from files_list so that i can further use it.

Comment: import os
import glob
import pandas as pd
paths = os.listdir(r"\\USER-PC\Users\user\Desktop\combined")
csvfiles = []
for path in paths:
    if path.endswith(".csv"):
        csvfiles.append(path)
csvfiles
df = [pd.read_csv(f) for f in csvfiles]

Comment: Cant you just use `files_list[0]`, `files_list[1]`, etc? As I can see in you code, each item of `files_list` is a dataframe.

Comment: thanks...but if want a specific file in a specific index ..so can i filter it out using some keys or by one of the unique value in each file...as i want each file_list to be pasted at a specific range in a excel file.